# Body parameters parsing issue with swagger-tool middleware (on expressJS)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, swagger

With swagger 2.0 spec, i'm describing an 'operation' to add new resources:

A POST request with 3 parameters:

```
{
    name: "username",
    in: "header",
    description: "New user unsername",
    required: true,
    type: "string"
},
{
    name: "password",
    in: "header",
    description: "New user password",
    required: true,
    type: "string"
},
{
    name: "pensis",
    in: "body",
    description: "New pensis to create",
    required: true,
    schema: {
        properties: {
            content: {
                type: "string",
                description: "Content of this pensis stored as markdown text"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

I setup the POST request with the 3 previous parameters:

- username: "Bob",
- password: "Yo!",
- pensis: {
  content: "The content"
  }

I send the POST request, and when i parse it using **swagger-tool metadata 0.8.6** middleware, i get a strange response :

The value of **req.swagger.params.pensis.value** provided by this middleware is not:

- `{ content: 'The content' }`

but:

- `{ content: 'The content',
    username: 'ClementVidal',
    password: 'r' 
  }`

Do you have any idea about why those 3 parameters are merged together inside the same pensis object ??

Thanks for your help

Clément Vidal

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this.  I created a bug [swagger-tools/issues/212](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/212) and it includes the diff of the test I wrote to attempt to reproduce this.  Feel free to update the issue with your feedback.  At this point, without explicit details, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.
I will investigate that using your test.

Comment: Ok, you are right, everythings works fine....
This was my own fault , sorry !

Comment: No problem, that's why I'm here.  :)  I really want to make Swagger and Node.js easier so when things aren't working, or aren't working like you'd expect, I want to know so I can fix it.